# How come Goldstone boson, PQWQ axion, be able to have mass at all?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model, axion

Quote:

> Goldstone's theorem: For every spontaneously broken continuous symmetry, there is a massless particle created by the symmetry current.

However, under $U(1)_{PQ}$ symmetry, I read that PQWW axion can obtain mass from $G\tilde{G}$.

Both these sentence make sense, but, being a Goldstone boson, there seemed to be a contraction around PQWW axion.

I read that this might be connect with the approximation from t' Hooft's determinental interaction. Could you explain to me what the determinental  interaction was?
Does that mean Goldstone's theorem only works for the first order of t' Hooft determinental interaction?

Does PQWW boson has mass or not?
Could you explain to me why a Goldstone could every obtain a mass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the pions, the axion is a pseudo-Golstone boson, so it has a mass. The $U(1)_{PQ}$, as a chiral symmetry, is broken by quantum corrections by the axion's coupling to gluons, and so is no longer an exact symmetry. Goldstone's theorem them does not apply. This is completely analagous to the so-called '$U(1)$ problem', where the $\eta '$ was seen to be too heavy to be a Goldstone boson. The resolution of this puzzle by 't Hooft made physical the CP-violating $G\tilde{G}$ term in the Lagrangian, which is what suggests a QCD axions in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, just to clearify a definition: any spontaneously broken symmetry is an approximate symmetry, and the associated particle is pseudo goldstone boson instead of goldstone boson? (I got messed up here because apparently I read a beautiful case whcih explain the concepts, but the author used chiral transformation and stated that pion was goldstone boson under approximation, and forgot to clearly until may be later. )

Comment: The phrase spontaneously broken is a bad phrase (yet we still use it). If there is a spontaneously broken symmetry, there is a Goldstone boson and it is massless. This is because the symmetry still exists (!), but we cannot naively see it in the vacuum state. If the symmetry that was 'spontaneously broken' was not exact, but only approximate (like if the up and down quarks have small masses, there is an approximate SU2xSU2 symmetry), then it is a pseudo-Goldstone boson. This is because there was never really a symmetry in the first place!

Comment: Additionally, everything I said is only true for global symmetries.

Answer (score 2):

Two conditions for pseudo goldstone boson:

1. The broken symmetry is not gauged, otherwise the (pseudo)
   goldstone boson will be eaten by the gauge field.
2. Something else (chiral anomaly in this case) breaks the symmetry
   even before the spontaneous symmetry breaking is taking place.

To visualize, think about a tilted Mexican hat potential. The lateral move in the tilted Mexican hat groove would be uphills (non-zero mass), as opposed to being flat (massless) for the usual Mexican hat potential. The non-zero mass of the pseudo goldstone boson would be very small if there is only a tiny bit tilting.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate a little bit what you meant by the broken symmetry is not gauged? (The symmetry being a gauge term in Lagrangian density?) And how does this eaten work exactly? Does it have to do with gluon coupling as gmarocco has mentioned?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate, "not gauged" means global symmetry such as the chiral symmetry, whereas gauged symmetry are local such as the electroweak $SU(2)*U(1)$, where the would-be Higgs goldstone bosons are eaten by the $W^{\pm}/Z$ gauge fields.